# How do I format a Post back including date in the title (using Linq and C# if possible)

Tags: c#, linq, listview

<asp:Button ID="Btn3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BkTime3", "{0: hh tt}")%>' (This works fine the postBackUrl doesn't) PostBackUrl='~/contact/VidLink.aspx?Topic=<%# Eval("BkTime3", "{0: dddd, dd MMMM, hh tt}")%>' />

I am using a ListView and it will not allow me to reference on IDs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an appointment calendar where selecting a date/time redirects to an email page with the selected date/time in the header these date/times are stored on the DB as DateTimes